# Trace Bitmap in Inkscape is removing transparent background

Tags: vector, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape and I'm trying to "vectorize" (trace bitmap) a .png image with transparent background.  Each time I execute the transparency is replaced with white background.  Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the white paths after tracing?

Comment: Or use the 'remove background' option.